# Query Term elimination

Tags: theory, information-retrieval

In boolean retrieval model query consist of terms which are combined together using different operators. Conjunction is most obvious choice at first glance, but when query length growth bad things happened. Recall dropped significantly when using conjunction and precision dropped when using disjunction (for example, `stanford OR university`).

As for now we use conjunction is our search system (and boolean retrieval model). And we have a problem if user enter some very rare word or long sequence of word. For example, if user enters `toyota corolla 4wd automatic 1995`, we probably doesn't have one. But if we delete at least one word from a query, we have such documents. As far as I understand in Vector Space Model this problem solved automatically. We does not *filter* documents on the fact of term presence, we *rank* documents using presence of terms.

So I'm interested in more advanced ways of combining terms in boolean retrieval model and methods of rare term elimination in boolean retrieval model.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the sky's the limit in terms of defining a ranking function here. You could define a vector  where the wi are: 0 if the ith search term doesn't appear in the file, 1 if it does; the number of times search term i appears in the file; etc. Then, rank pages based on e.g. Manhattan distance, Euclidean distance, etc. and sort in descending order, possibly culling results with distance below a specified match tolerance.

If you want to handle more complex queries, you can put the query into CNF - e.g. (term1 or term2 or ... termn) AND (item1 or item2 or ... itemk) AND ... and then redefine the weights wi accordingly. You could list with each result the terms that failed to match in the file... so that the users would at least know how good a match it is.

I guess what I'm really trying to say is that to really get an answer that works for you, you have to define exactly what you are willing to accept as a valid search result. Under the strict interpretation, a query that is looking for A1 and A2 and ... Am *should* fail if any of the terms is missing...

Comment: Really good point. What we are trying to achieve at the moment is maximize recall even if loose some level of precision. We think that it's very bad when search system says: "No documents found". On the other way, when people get a lot of not relevant results, they typically knows how to refine query. So we are trying to minimize cases when search system doesn't find any documents.